# java - check whether a string contains any characters other than spaces

Tags: java, string

I need to check if a string contains any symbols other than a space. I cant check with

```
      String.length() > 0
```

or

```
      String.equals("")
```

since spaces are considered as characters. How can I find out whether a java String contains other characters (letters, symbols, numbers, whatever) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
String.trim().equals("")
```

If String only contains spaces they all will be removed by `trim()` before checking for equality

Comment: trim() will remove more than just spaces and not do what Maver1ck asks for.

Answer (score 6):

Just [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) the string (remember to check for `null` before invoking a method on it):

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

```
 myString != null && !myString.trim().isEmpty();
```

Or, if you're using Apache Commons, you can use [StringUtils.isBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29). You can check its [implementation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.227).

Comment: `!"".equals(myString.trim());` => `!myString.trim().isEmpty()` would look better

Answer (score 2):

Whyn not use `String.trim()` and check if the resultant length is greater than 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression, `"[^ ]"` would do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
String test;
//populate test

if(test.trim().length() > 0)
{
//Bingo
}else{
//Uff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all spaces:

```
String s = ...;
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Then check the length:

```
if(s.length() > 0)
```

or check if a string is empty:

```
if (s.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 2):

With a regex:

`myString.matches("[^ ]+"); // all but spaces`

Answer (score 2):

Using Google Guava:

```
CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.negate().matchesAnyOf(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trim your string and then check it for empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, to remove all the space characters and then to measure its length:

```
                string.replaceAll("\\s","")
                int length=string.length();
```

In this case, if length is greater than zero, it does contain  non-space characters.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringUtils from apache commons:
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/index.html